# Demasiados h1 en este código

Tags: html5

Pues según tengo entendido, en una página no es bueno poner más de un h1 ni abusar de los h2, h3... La cuestión es que me han dado una actividad de clase para maquetar con grid y al ver la cantidad de h1 que tiene, he pensado que estaba mal y me gustaría arreglarlo, pero no sé exactamente cómo debería quedar, ¿Qué me recomendáis?

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>HTML5</title>

</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <h2>Subtitle</h2>
    </header>
    <div id="container">
        <nav>
            <h3>Nav</h3>
            <a href="">Link 1</a>
            <a href="">Link 2</a>
            <a href="">Link 3</a>
        </nav>
        <section>
            <article>
                <header>
                    <h1>Article Header</h1> 
                </header>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor HTML5 nunc aut nunquam sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at est eros,
                    vel fringilla urna.</p>
                <p>Per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque feugiat, justo at vehicula pellentesque, turpis lorem dictum nunc.
                </p>

                <footer>
                    <h2>Article Footer</h2>
                </footer>
            </article>
            <article>
                <header>
                    <h1>Article Header</h1>
                </header>
                <p>HTML5: "Lorem ipsum dolor nunc aut nunquam sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at est
                    eros, vel fringilla urna. Pellentesque odio</p>
                <footer>
                    <h2>Article Footer</h2>
                </footer>
            </article>
        </section>
        <aside>
            <h3>Aside</h3>
            <p>HTML5: "Lorem ipsum dolor nunc aut nunquam sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at est eros,
                vel fringilla urna. Pellentesque odio rhoncus</p>
        </aside>
        <footer>
            <h2>Footer</h2>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

¿Veis alguna otra modificación semántica de etiquetas que no esté bien?

Comment: agrega un estilo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El punto de partida es erróneo y eso te puede conducir a cometer errores (de organización o de lógica) o a dolores de cabeza innecesarios:

> Pues según tengo entendido, en una página no es bueno poner más de un
>   h1 ni abusar de los h2, h3...

Eso no es cierto:

- En ninguna parte se prohibe o desaconseja tener más de una `h1` por página, lo que sí se prohibe es tener más de una `h1` por `section`
- En ninguna parte se prohibe no abusar de los `h2`, `h3`, etc. Cuando creas un contenido organizado debes usar tantos `h2`, `h3` como elementos dependientes existan. Si por naturaleza tienes un contenido que debe llevar `n` etiquetas `h2`, lo penoso sería recurrir a acciones truculentas para negar parte de esos `h2` convirtiéndolos en otra cosa. Si el contenido debe llevar `n` etiquetas `h2` pónselas, respeta la naturaleza de tu contenido.

Las **Notas de uso** en el apartado [Elementos Título](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/Elementos_t%C3%ADtulos) de MDN son suficientemente aclaratorias para sustentar las dos afirmaciones anteriores (pondré algunas negritas para resaltarlo):

> **Notas de uso:**
>
> - No se deben usar niveles inferiores **para reducir el tamaño de la fuente**: use la propiedad CSS `font-size` para eso.
> - Evite omitir niveles de encabezado: siempre comience con `<h1>`, después use `<h2>` y así sucesivamente.
> - Con el elemento `<section>`, debe considerar evitar usar `<h1>` más de una vez en una página; por costumbre, se usa para mostrar el título
>     de la página, con todos los encabezados debajo de éste comenzando con
>     `<h2>`. **Cuando se usan secciones, debe usarse un `<h1>` por
>     sección**.

Si observas los ejemplos, tanto en la [especificación de HTML 5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements), como en [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document#Definiendo_secciones_en_HTML5), podrás ver que, cuando el contenido se organiza por secciones, se empieza siempre con `h1` y se sigue con los otros niveles.

Otra cosa **muy importante** es [lo dicho aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document#Definiendo_secciones_en_HTML5) (las negritas son mías):

> Todo el contenido incluido dentro del elemento `<body>` es parte de
>   una sección. Las secciones en HTML5 pueden ser anidadas. Además de la
>   sección principal, definida por el elemento `<body>`, los límites de
>   la sección son definidos **explícita o implícitamente**. La secciones
>   definidas explícitamente son el contenido definido en las etiquetas
>   `<body>`,  `<section>`,  `<article>`,  `<aside>`, `<footer>`, 
>   `<header>`, y `<nav>`.

Esto quiere decir que cuando defines por ejemplo `<header>`  o `<article>` estás en una sección implícita, por tanto, esto es totalmente válido:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Encabezado</h1>
    </header>

    <section>
        <h1>Titulo sección 1</h1>
    </section>

    <article>
        <h1>Titulo articulo A</h1>
    </article>
</body>
```

### Conclusión

Si el contenido que muestras en la pregunta corresponde a la naturaleza jerárquica de lo que representa, no recurras a soluciones oscuras para negar ciertos encabezados creyendo que incurres en una falta que no existe realmente.

Answer (score 2):

Te he colocado todas mis recomendaciones en los comentarios del html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>HTML5</title>

</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <!-- Si los dos titulos estan fuertemente relacionados y que hablen de lo mismo o que su objetivo sea el mismo puedes usar un  hgroup -->
        <hgroup>
            <h1>Header</h1>
            <h2>Subtitle</h2>
        </hgroup>
    </header>
    <div id="container">
        <!-- Un navbar nunca deberia de llevar un titulo ya que este es un menu por lo mismo en el extraño caso de que llegase a llevar un titulo tendria que ser por fuera del nav y ademas tendria que ser con un h3 a lo mucho -->
        <h3>Nav</h3>
        <nav>
            <a href="">Link 1</a>
            <a href="">Link 2</a>
            <a href="">Link 3</a>
        </nav>
        <section>
            <article>
                <!-- Usar mas de un header esta mal, los buscadores como google penalizan esto debido a que header se refiere al contenido de encabezado y descatado por lo que si tienes mas de uno se considera una mala practica al crear una pagina en html -->
                <!-- Al estar hablando de un article daremos por entendido de que habra varios article por lo que sera necesario que se agregue cuando mucho un h5 a cada uno como encabezado a menos de que se tratara del arciculo principal del dia o algo asi -->
                <h5>Article Header</h5> 
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor HTML5 nunc aut nunquam sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at est eros,
                    vel fringilla urna.</p>
                <p>Per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque feugiat, justo at vehicula pellentesque, turpis lorem dictum nunc.
                </p>

                <!-- No puede existir mas de un footer en la pagina por lo que esta parte esta del todo mal, en caso de que le quisieras agregar un footer a un artible tendria que ir en un div -->
                <div class="footer-div-article">
                    <!-- Mas de un encabezado dentro de un article estaria mal establecido ya que al encontrarse hasta abajo como representacion de una especie de footer se trataria de un titulo sin importancia por lo cual no puede ser conciderado un titulo para empezar, esto deberia de ir con un span -->
                    <span>Article Footer</span>
                </div>
            </article>
            <!-- Aplica lo mismo que te dije arriba para este article -->
            <article>
                <h1>Article Header</h1>
                <p>HTML5: "Lorem ipsum dolor nunc aut nunquam sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at est
                    eros, vel fringilla urna. Pellentesque odio</p>
                <div class="footer-div-article">
                    <span>Article Footer</span>
                </div>
            </article>
        </section>
        <aside>
            <!-- En este caso esta bien definido el aside, tal vez la unica recomendacion que te podria hacer es que el h fuera un h4 o 5 -->
            <h4>Aside</h4>
            <p>HTML5: "Lorem ipsum dolor nunc aut nunquam sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at est eros,
                vel fringilla urna. Pellentesque odio rhoncus</p>
        </aside>
        <!-- Al tratarse de un footer que es el ultimo contenido te recomendaria que el h a lo mucho fuera un h6 ya que este contenido no tiene importancia semantica para los buscadores -->
        <footer>
            <h6>Footer</h6>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

> Te recuerdo que en una pagina web solo debe de existir un h1 por recomendación ademas de que el posicionamiento de tu pagina web mejora en gran medida y un h2 se recomienda poner un máximo de dos pero lo recomendable es uno solamente igual que con el h1.

Comment: Buena, creo que yo me fui mas por el stylo XD

Comment: Bueno entre las 2 respuestas puede hacer una bonita práctica te deje mi voto, saludos man.

Answer (score 1):

La verdad todo depende de ti que tanto quieras darle diseño a esa practica, puedes importar nuevas fuentes como te lo puse en este ejemplo, lo importas en tu head desde [GoogleFonts](https://fonts.google.com/) y puedes agregar animaciones a cada etiqueta desde [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/).

Te deje un estilo que puedes utilizar, esta claro que puedes probar como tu lo quieras...espero te sirva.

```css
.personalizado {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>HTML5</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <p class="personalizado animated tada">Personalizado</p>
    </header>
    <div id="container">
        <nav>
            <h3>Nav</h3>
            <a href="">Link 1</a>
            <a href="">Link 2</a>
            <a href="">Link 3</a>
        </nav>
        <section>
            <article>
                <header>
                    <h1>Article Header</h1> 
                </header>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor HTML5 nunc aut nunquam sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at est eros,
                    vel fringilla urna.</p>
                <p>Per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque feugiat, justo at vehicula pellentesque, turpis lorem dictum nunc.
                </p>

                <footer>
                    <h2>Article Footer</h2>
                </footer>
            </article>
            <article>
                <header>
                    <h1>Article Header</h1>
                </header>
                <p>HTML5: "Lorem ipsum dolor nunc aut nunquam sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at est
                    eros, vel fringilla urna. Pellentesque odio</p>
                <footer>
                    <h2>Article Footer</h2>
                </footer>
            </article>
        </section>
        <aside>
            <h3>Aside</h3>
            <p>HTML5: "Lorem ipsum dolor nunc aut nunquam sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at est eros,
                vel fringilla urna. Pellentesque odio rhoncus</p>
        </aside>
        <footer>
            <h2>Footer</h2>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```